# Can't use MediaPlayer.seekTo in onPrepared()

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to call MediaPlayer.seekTo() from onPrepared callback :

```
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.seekTo(2000); // the audio files I use are about 3 minutes long
}
```

This works fine on Android 4.0 but on Android 6.0 I get -38 error code.

Edit : Problem solved : I was calling pause() in an invalid state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved : I was calling pause() in an invalid state.